# Error with creating customer for Stripe payment

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, e-commerce, stripe-payments

I have an ASP .NET Core MVC e-commerce app where I'm trying to implement payments using Stripe. I've implemented the solution as outlined in [this guide](https://stripe.com/docs/checkout/aspnet) but for some reason I'm getting the error `Stripe.StripeException: 'Cannot charge a customer that has no active card'` in the charge method which is called when the user initiates a payment.

The issue seems to be caused by the fact that the stripe email and the stripe token, which are the two parameters that actually being passed into the charge method, are receiving null arguments. I'm not sure why these variables are getting null values when the function is called as I have followed all of the steps outlined in the stripe tutorial.

I've used both the test and live secret and publishable keys from the stripe dashboard and have properly included them in the appsettings json file. The code from the relevant files is below. ***What could be causing this error here?***

**stripe charge controller action**

```
public IActionResult Charge(string stripeEmail, string stripeToken)
        {
            var customerService = new StripeCustomerService();
            var chargeService = new StripeChargeService();

            var customer = customerService.Create(new StripeCustomerCreateOptions
            {
                Email = stripeEmail,
                SourceToken = stripeToken
            });

            var charge = chargeService.Create(new StripeChargeCreateOptions
            {
                Amount = 500,
                Description = "ASP .NET Core Stripe Tutorial",
                Currency = "usd",
                CustomerId = customer.Id
            });

            return View();
        }
```

**appsettings.json**

```
"Stripe": {
    "SecretKey": "sk_test...",
    "PublishableKey": "pk_test..."
  }
```

**charge view page**

```
@using Microsoft.Extensions.Options
@inject IOptions<StripeSettings> Stripe

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "MakePayment";
}

<form action="/Order/Charge" method="post">
    <article>
        <label>Amount: $5.00</label>
    </article>
    <script src="//checkout.stripe.com/v2/checkout.js"
            class="stripe-button"
            data-key="@Stripe.Value.PublishableKey"
            data-locale="auto"
            data-description="Sample Charge"
            data-amount="500">
    </script>
</form>
<h2>MakePayment</h2>
```

**Stripe settings class**

```
public class StripeSettings
    {
        public string SecretKey { get; set; }
        public string PublishableKey { get; set; }
    }
```

**Startup.cs**

```
       public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
                options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("Cn")));

            services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>()
                .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
                .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

            // Add application services.
            services.AddTransient<IEmailSender, EmailSender>();
            services.AddDbContext<wywytrav_DBContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("Cn")));
            services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();
            services.AddScoped(sp => ShoppingCart.GetCart(sp));
            services.AddScoped<SignInManager<ApplicationUser>, SignInManager<ApplicationUser>>();
            services.AddTransient<IOrderRepository, OrderRepository>();
            services.AddMvc();
            services.AddMemoryCache();
            services.AddSession();

            services.Configure<StripeSettings>(Configuration.GetSection("Stripe"));//stripe configuration
        }

        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
        {

            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseBrowserLink();
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
                app.UseDatabaseErrorPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
            }

            app.UseStaticFiles();
            app.UseSession();
            app.UseAuthentication();
            StripeConfiguration.SetApiKey(Configuration.GetSection("Stripe")["SecretKey"]);
}
```

Comment: The issue here is likely just that `stripeToken` is empty. You need to investigate this in your code to confirm whether it's set properly to tok_XXXX or not

Comment: Your code looks fine. Ensure that the correct Strip publishable key is being inserted into the script tag. Try inspecting the request with something like Fiddler, and ensure that Stripe is sending a good token with the proper param name. Debug and step through your action method. Ensure that your params are filled correctly, and that the customer creation step is succeeding. (As you have it now, if customer creation fails, you still attempt to make a charge against the customer that was not in fact created.)

Comment: @koopajah Yes, the stripe token  and the stripe email are empty as they are passed into the `Charge()` method. Where are they supposed to be set?

Comment: They come from the client, when Checkout fills the information and sends it to your server. So they would need to be set in your route or the code that receives the POST request in that case

Comment: @koopajah Actually, I was requesting the wrong url. Now that the actual view for the stripe payment is being requested, the correct stripe data is being sent to the controller.